# CAS authentication and redirects with jQuery AJAX

Tags: authentication, redirect, jquery

I've got an HTML page that needs to make requests to a CAS-protected ([Central Authentication Service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_Authentication_Service)) web service using the jQuery AJAX functions. I've got the following code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: request,
    dataType: "json",
    complete: function(xmlHttp) {
        console.log(xmlHttp);
        alert(xmlHttp.status);
    },
    success: handleRedirects
});
```

The `request` variable can be either to the CAS server (`https://cas.mydomain.com/login?service=myServiceURL`) or directly to the service (which should then redirect back to CAS to get a service ticket). Firebug shows that the request is being made and that it comes back as a 302 redirect. However, the `$.ajax()` function isn't handling the redirect.

I wrote this function to work around this:

```
var handleRedirects = function(data, textStatus) {
    console.log(data, textStatus);
    if (data.redirect) {
       console.log("Calling a redirect: " + data.redirect);
       $.get(data.redirect, handleRedirects);
    } else {
        //function that handles the actual data processing
        gotResponse(data);
    }
};
```

However, even with this, the `handleRedirects` function never gets called, and the `xmlHttp.status` always returns `0`. It also doesn't look like the cookies are getting sent with the cas.mydomain.com call. (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887742/ajax-call-through-cas) for a similar problem.)

Is this a problem with the AJAX calls not handling redirects, or is there more going on here than meets the eye?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is indeed more going on than meets the eye.

After some investigation, it appears that jQuery AJAX requests made in this way fail if they're not made to the same subdomain. In this example, requests are being made to `cas.mydomain.com` from a different server. Even if it is also on `mydomain.com`, the request will fail because the *subdomain doesn't match*.

jQuery AJAX does handle redirects properly. I did some testing with scripts on the same subdomain to verify that. In addition, cookies are also passed as you would expect. See [my blog post](http://globalconstant.scnay.com/2010/06/05/jquery-ajax-doesnt-work-across-subdomains/) for this research.

Also keep in mind that the protocols must be the same. That is, since `cas.mydomain.com` is using HTTPS, the page from which you are calling it must also be on HTTPS or the request will fail.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?  I read your blog post suggesting JSONP, which is what I've read elsewhere.  However, it looks like CORS is the way to get around this, but I still can't get the 302 redirects to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

Cross domain calls are not allowed by the browser. The simplest way would be to use JSONP on the mobile application end and use a CAS gateway to return a ticket.

Answer (score 1):

You can make such cross-domain AJAX calls with a PHP proxy. In the following example the proxy is capable of calling REST web services that return a JSON string.

**wsproxy.php**

```php
<?php

if (!isset($_POST["username"]) || !isset($_POST["password"]))
    die("Username or password not set.");

$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

if (!isset($_GET['url'])
    die("URL was not set.");

//Rebuild URL (needed if the url passed as GET parameter
//also contains GET parameters
$url = $_GET['url'];
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) { 
    if ($key != 'url') {
        $url .= "&" . $key . "=" . $value;
    }
}

//Set username and password for HTTP Basic Authentication
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
    'header'  => "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$username:$password")
    )
));

//Call WS
$json = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

// Read HTTP Status
if(isset($http_response_header[0]))
    list($version,$status_code,$msg) =
        explode(' ',$http_response_header[0], 3);

// Check HTTP Status
if($status_code != 200) {
    if($status_code == 404) {
        die("404 - Not Found");
    } else {
        die($status_code . " - Error");
    }
}

//Add content header
header('Content-Type: application/json');
print $json;

?>
```

**URL usage**

> http://yourDomain.com/wsproxy.php?url=https://wsToCall.com/ws/resource?param1=false&param2=true

**jQuery [`$.ajax`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) or [`$.post`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)**

Note that if you don't need to pass username and password, then a GET request is sufficient.

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "http://" + document.domain +
        "/wsproxy.php?url=http://wsToCall.com/ws/resource?param1=false&param2=true",
    dataType : "json",
    success : handleRedirects,
    data: { username: "foo", password: "bar" }
});
```

Comment: A problem you might run into with this is that the proxy won't be using the user's session information. In my case I was trying to log the user into a CAS service by sending a server-side request to the CAS server - the service ticket I got back did authenticate them on the service but they were not logged into the server itself (losing some of the benefit of having an SSO setup to begin with).