# Allow cross domain scripting in mvc web application

Tags: tomcat, spring-mvc, cross-domain

I have a web application and im using spring mvc.
I need to allow cross domain scripting (i need that a web service that i externalize can be accessed by javascript).
I wrote a crossdomain.xml and i put it under the WEB-INF folder. This is my crossdomain.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cross-domain-policy>
  <allow-access-from domain="*" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

I have searched around and saw that the crossdomain.xml should be accessable from this URL:
"*localhost:8080/crossdomain.xml*"
the thing is that the mvc is rerouting the request to the main controller (with RequestMapping annotation of "/"). How can i overcome this using spring mvc?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a special integration between jax rs jersey implementation and spring. all explained in this blog
[Jersey Spring integration](https://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/jersey_and_spring)

Answer (score 1):

crossdomain.xml is used *only* by flash, so that's probably not what you actually want.

If you want cross domain xhr requests done with javascript, you should be using either CORS or JSONP, see this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10047584/browser-doesnt-follow-redirect-from-an-ajax-response-php-generated-response-i/10048020#10048020)

CORS example:

```
access-control-allow-origin: http://api.example.com
access-control-allow-credentials: true
```

JSONP example (with jQuery, requires server side support):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://domain.com/jsonp-service",
    dataType: "JSONP"
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.when i use the dataType: JSONP the jquery ajax returns an error. same thing happens whern i write json.
The thing is that im using JAX-RS (jersey) to externalize the service and i read around that there is no support for jsonp in jax-rs so i searched for a filter but didn't find a working one :) 
any suggestions?

Comment: I found the solution. There is a special integration between spring and jersey. after implementing that, it worked. (i used JSONP at the end). thanks a lot.