# Not able to use ajax in spring mvc form

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, spring-mvc

I am trying to implement ajax based post in form in spring mvc.

Here is my code:

```
<form:form method="POST" commandName="emailDomain">
    <form:textarea path="emailText" rows="5" id="emailList"
        placeholder="Write emails to submit us, saperated by ';'"
        style="width: 100%" />

<form:select items="${categoryMap}" path="categoryId" id="categoryList"
    onchange="showEmails()" />

    <br />
    <p align="center">
        <button type="button" value="Submit" id="submitEmails">Submit emails</button>
    </p>
    <p align="center" class="text-info">${var}</p>
</form:form>
```

My ajax code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script>

     <script type="text/javascript">
     function showEmails() {

            var categoryId = $('#categoryList').val();
    var emailText = $('#emailList').val();

    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "http://localhost:8081/chatbooster/forms/email.html?cat=1",
                data : "categoryId=" + categoryId + "&emailText=" + emailText,
        success : function(response) {


        },
        error:function (xhRequest, ErrorText, thrownError) {
            alert('Error: '  + '  ' + thrownError);
        }
    });
}
```

The problem is after clicking the button, it shows error as alert but with out any explanation. And after that it is jumping to page showing json response. The code would work if I do not use spring form tag at all. It will show no error and wont show json response but again, I will not able to populate select dropdown from database.

My controller is:

```
@Controller
  @RequestMapping(value = "/email.html")
  public class EmailController{

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
      public String showForm(Model model,
          @RequestParam(value = "cat", required = true) String category,
          HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        clearSession(request, response);

        return "email";
      }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/submitemails", method = RequestMethod.GET)
      public @ResponseBody
      String submitAndRefreshEmails() {
        System.out.println("check");

        return "email";
      }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
      public @ResponseBody
      EmailJsonResponse addEmail(@Valid EmailDomain emailDomain,
          BindingResult result,
          @RequestParam(value = "cat", required = true) String category,
          HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
      throws Exception {

        //return emailjsonresponse object, a simple object carrying few ints and strings

      }

    @ModelAttribute("categoryMap")
      public Map<Long, String> populateCategoryList(
          @RequestParam(value = "cat", required = true) String category)
      throws Exception {

        // populating drop down 

      }

  }
```

I have read many discussion about this but I am not able to get how to make it situation like this? Can anyone please help me out here? I am referring this example http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/02/spring-mvc-and-jquery-for-ajax-form.html

**Edit 1:**

I have even tried this new one:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#submitEmails').onclick(function() {
          $.getJSON('http://localhost:8081/chatbooster/forms/submitemails.html?cat=1',
                {
                    categoryId : $('#categoryList').val(),
                    emailText : $('#emailList').val(),
                    ajax : 'true'
                }, 
                function(data) {
                    alert('data found');
                }
          );
      });
  });
```

But still I am being shown json response. I am not able to understand why it is happening? I tried out this http://rockhoppertech.com/blog/spring-mvc-3-cascading-selects-using-jquery/. I am able to implement ajax when I don't use spring form component. But that will cause trouble to me for populating drop down element from database. There is something that I am missing. Any ideas what it can be ?

**Edit 2**

Now I understand what is the cause of this issue. It is that I am submitting the form which is eventually leading to me to json response. What I need to do is to call jquery function from the button, making submit button of button type rather than submit type. Clicking on that would call method related to GET request type of the controller. But for that I need to call submitAndRefreshEmails method on clicking submit button. Can anyone please tell me how to go for that? How to call a particular method of GET type when there are many such type of methods in a controller?

Comment: Is the page containing this also loaded from `http://localhost:8081/`? Otherwise, your request would violate the SOP. Try setting the `crossDomain` parameter.

Comment: @vlad halmer Inside your ajax call, I am not seeing `data` being submitted?  Looks like your `addEmail` method is expecting a valid `EmailDomain` object...

Comment: @user1766760 As you have said, I have added data : "categoryId=" + categoryId + "&emailText=" + emailText in my ajax call. So, the controller is able to get the data from view but after submitting the form, the page s displaying json response. I have edited the ajax call in view page.

Comment: @CBrow Yes, the page is running in localhost. I am calling localhost url to call its respective controller. I am not able to understand about crossDomain parameter. Can you please tell me a basic about it or any link? DO you mean something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11377994/allow-cross-domain-scripting-in-mvc-web-application

Comment: On the MVC-side, you would need a Controller method mapped to some URL that would return your submitAndRefreshEmails method.  Then you simply use that mapped URL to call it.

Comment: Can anyone please help me here...I am looking for https://github.com/genedelisa/springFormWithCascadingSelects/blob/master/src/main/java/com/rockhoppertech/spring/web/RegistrationController.java but not able to understand why its not making out in my scene? I have tried many url patters.

Comment: @vladhalmer I see you have updated your post. See my response below.  You may have better luck getting help by submitting a new post as you encounter new, different issue.

Comment: @CodeChimp: Your suggestion worked for me...actually I created a new controller for submitAndRefreshEmails method. That way it is taking up the request for Json response :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are doing an AJAX call, you are expecting to return a snippet of info (your JSON data) without (re)loading the HTML page.  Hence the usage of `@ResponseBody`.

If the AJAX call is bound to a form submit, it will trigger a page load (I can't seem to find a good source that explains this).  Therefore, you will need to stop the default behavior.

```
$form.bind('submit', function(e) {
    $.post('epdReviewSaveChanges.json', mData, function(response) {
            //do stuff...
    }

    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

A little explanation on the above, taken from [here](http://css-tricks.com/return-false-and-prevent-default/).

`e.preventDefault()` part of that code prevents the browser from performing the default action.  `return false;` takes things a bit further in that it also prevents that event from propagating (or "bubbling up") the DOM.

I suspect the original problem you have has more to do with how to use AJAX calls/Spring.  I am not speaking to any cross-domain issues, which may require additional / different solution.

**Problem 2** As to mapping to a specific method within a controller, you can use the `value` to differentiate between the different calls. Ex:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/Upload.html",method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response...I have not used preventDefault to solve my issue but yes I have mapped different  value to my method returning Json response and that method is defined in different controller.