# How to Overcome Cross-domain Issues for Ajax Calls to CAS-protected Resources?

Tags: ajax, authentication, cookies, redirect, cas

What are potential solutions to a redirection problem that occurs when trying to make AJAX calls to a CAS-protected, SSL-encrypted resource located on a server different from the CAS server?

The CAS server is used for authentication and behaves as designed.   This issue appears to be ajax-specific.

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961051/cas-authentication-and-redirects-with-jquery-ajax), but we cannot use the same domain/server/port for the CAS server and the backend resource.

The [JASIG CAS](https://lists.wisc.edu/read/messages?id=7777296#7777296) mailing lists mentions using JSESSIONID.

Another possible approach is to modify the CAS Filter to change the expired-ticket default behavior to something more robust.

What design pattern would you use to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I have 2 suggestions:

- can you **set up a proxy script on the same domain** as the one that holds the JS code? That way the proxy script would query the CAS and return desired results
- can you enable JSONP? this type of request is not limited by the security policy (but then anyone could use the service)

Answer (score 0):

I never heard about CAS, but in general: Javascript has some restriction called “same origin policy”. A visible ressource is not automatically visible to Javascript, too. Did you try to access the ressource using a reverse proxy to make it available within the same domain? You could also consider to point your domain onto a separate web server and include both servers as reverse proxies (for Tomacat, JKmounts are to prefer) here.