# ajax call to timed-out cas-protected server: ajax redirection problem

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, cas

Our web server uses CAS for single sign on.   The CAS server is running the JASIG CAS server on https://portal.ourdomain.com and the web server is running Rails on http://service.ourdomain.com.

The Rails server has its session timeout set fairly low as a single sign-out backup measure and for other reasons.   So occasionally, users do get redirected to portal.ourdomain.com for reauthentication.   Normally this is seamless since portal.ourdomain.com immediately redirects them back to service.ourdomain.com with an updated ticket cookie unless the CAS session has expired.

However, this doesn't work for AJAX.   Web browsers do not follow redirects for XHR requests, even if the domain is the same.

One obvious solution would be to serve everything from https://ourdomain.com and stop with the subdomain nonsense.   This is an extensive operation and would require serving everything through https.

Another solution would be to regularly ping the server so that it never times out.     Besides the increased load on the server, having pages that never time out defeats the purpose of having the timeout in the first place.

Which leads to the third, crappy solution: just remove the timeout.

[How to Overcome Cross-domain Issues for Ajax Calls to CAS-protected Resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5589881/how-to-overcome-cross-domain-issues-for-ajax-calls-to-cas-protected-resources) is a similar question which is unanswered, but that question appears to be broader, so I hope there's an answer to our question.

Does anybody have any solutions to this problem that don't suck?

Answer (score 0):

You only can wrap the ajax xhr requestwhendoing revalidation, so that the browser can understand the redirect. That would need to change code for the cas proxy.
This "work around must be checked and extended (in worst case) for every kind of ajax web framework. We did it for jquery, which gladly is ajax base for rails3.

Comment: Are you saying that you wrap $.ajax?   Could you possible post your code?   What does it do?   Let me guess, it somehow catches the error, pops up an authentication dialog, then resends the request?